# The uniqueness of an element in the intersection of nested intervals.

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $S$ is a nonempty subset of $\mathbb{R}$ and $S \subseteq [a_0, b_0]$ where $a_0, b_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ and $a_0 < b_0$. Let $m_1 = \frac{a_0 + b_0}{2}$  be the midpoint of $[a_0, b_0]$. If $[m_1, b_0] \cap S = \emptyset$, define $a_1 = a_0$ and $b_1 = m_1$; otherwise define $a_1 = m_1$ and $b_1 = b_0$. From this, define an interval $I_1 = [a_1, b_1]$. Next, let $m_2 = \frac{a_1 + b_1}{2}$ be the midpoint of $[a_1, b_1]$. If $[m_2, b_1] \cap S = \emptyset$, define $a_2 = a_1$ and $b_2 = m_2$; otherwise define $a_2 = m_2$ and $b_2 = b_1$. From this, we can define an interval $I_2 = [a_2, b_2]$. Continuing in this manner, if $I_n = [a_n, b_n]$ is defined, let $m_{n+1} = \frac{a_n + b_n}{2}$ be the midpoint of $[a_n, b_n]$. If $[m_{n+1}, b_n] \cap S = \emptyset$, define $a_{n+1} = a_n$ and $b_{n+1} = m_{n+1}$; otherwise define $a_{n+1} = m_{n+1}$ and $b_{n+1} = b_n$. Then $I_{n+1} = [a_{n+1}, b_{n+1}]$ is defined. Continuing in this way, we can define a collection of intervals as $I_n$.

Prove there exists a unique element $\xi \in \bigcap\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} I_n$. Furthermore, show $\xi$ = sup$S$.

By showing the collection is nested, it is fairly simple to deduce that there exists a $\xi$ in the intersection of the intervals. However, I am struggling to show the element is unique and that it is also the supremum of $S$.

All help is greatly appreciated. I am new here and would like to say this place is awesome. Especially for an aspiring mathematician.

Answer (score 2):

If $x,y\in \bigcap_n I_n$, then $a_n\leqslant x,y\leqslant b_n$.
Then $|x-y|\leqslant b_n-a_n=(b_0-a_0)2^{-n}$, $\forall n$. Then $x=y$, that is, $\xi$ is unique.

We show that $s\triangleq \sup S\subset[a_n,b_n]$ for all $n$.
For $n=0$, this is true since $S\subset [a_0,b_0]$.
Now suppose this is true for $n-1$($n\geqslant 1$). Consider the case $n$.

If $s>m_n=(a_{n-1}+b_{n-1})/2$, then there must be some $y\in S$ satisfying $(s+m_n)/2\leqslant y\leqslant s$. Thus $a_n=m_n,b_n=b_{n-1}$ and $s\in[a_n,b_n]$.

If $s<m_n$, then $a_n=a_{n-1}, b_n=m_n$ and $s\in[a_n,b_n]$.

If $s=m_n$, then whenever $(a_n,b_n)=(a_{n-1},m_n)$ or $(a_n,b_n)=(m_n,b_{n-1})$, we know $s\in[a_n,b_n]$.

Then $a_n\leqslant s\leqslant b_n$ and $\lim_n a_n=\lim_n b_n=\xi$. Then $s=\xi$.
QED.